# How to handle a new window tab in selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I was trying to automate searching jobs in Naukri. when I do a search by category, it opens the window in a new Tab.

That window is served by a link, ex:

```
< a href="Naukri.com/jobs-by-cat">Jobs By Category < /a >
```

Now how can I make selenium execute the remaining commands in that new window?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use `waitForPopUp` and then `selectPopUp` to switch focus to the new tab.

Then all your operations will be performed on new tab or window. Once you are done using `close` will close the newly opened window and use `selectWindow` again to select your original window.

If this doesn't work, see if you can move to Webdriver because there are many more limitations for Selenium IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt find any direct solution for this but I discovered a workaround.
I actually copied the href attribute value of the < a> tag by the command "storeAttribute" and used a "open" command to open that url in the same window avoiding it to be opned in a new window.

I used it to automate Naukri job search :

Here is the code:

```
storeAttribute | link=Hotel Jobs@href | url <br/> 
open | ${url}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm also facing the same issue and I used the following script in the Selenium IDE.

Command: storeAttribute
Target: link=https://gkphealthcare.abcnet.net//amrc//onboard.do
Value: testurl

I put the following commands in the Next Line.

Command: open
Target: ${testurl}
Value:

It is not working for me.. :(
Anyone have answer this?
Thanks,
Karunagara Pandi

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and it is working for me..... :)

And here are the scripts that I have used for my testing...

**Line No: 1**

**Command:** storeAttribute 
**Target:** link=https://yourwebaddress.net/vmrc/onboard.do@href 
**Value:** testurl ( i.e. variable name )

**Line No: 2**

**Command:** open 
**Target:** ${testurl}

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
command: storeElementPresent
Target: link=... (or use id. Ex: company-id=2258)
Value: url <br/>
```

THEN:

```
command: open
Target: url
Value: url (or null)
```